# HTTP for one part of the site, HTTPS for other

Tags: security, https, authentication, http

We have a site which is HTTP, but it has an admin part. How can we secure the admin part with HTTPS?

For example, WordPress (which I know) is located at `http://foo.com`, but we want to have `https://foo.com/wp-admin/`

How to do this?

Comment: I would suggest adding the 'https' tag, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you already have an SSL certificate, and have Apache (or $HTTPD) configured properly to work with SSL requests. If this is a bad assumption, let me know.

Otherwise, the quickest way to wrangle WordPress into forcing SSL for logins/admin pages would be the [Admin SSL WP Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-ssl-secure-admin/). Install it, activate it, et voilá.

Answer (score 5):

A generic non-application way to force an entire directory and its subdirectories to use SSL can be achieved with Apache:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Simply put that in a the .htaccess file of the directory you wish to secure. If you put it in your root directory it will force your whole site to be secure.

Comment: Just looking at this old question (recently updated). This method is only part of the story (as described [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628)). Ultimately, it's only as secure as the user verifies it is.