# How to prevent access to website without SSL connection?

Tags: https

I have a website that has an SSL certificate installed, so that if I access the website using `https` instead of `http` I will be able to connect using a secure connection.

However, I have noticed that I can still access the website non-securely, ie. by using `http` instead of `https`.

How can I prevent people using the website in a non-secure manner?

If I have a directory on the website, eg. `samples/`, can I prevent non-secure connections to just this directory?

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, the only general solution to this problem is to give your users the `https://` only and make sure that they *expect* to use that only. It is ultimately the responsibility of the user to check that they are using SSL/TLS, as they expect.

Other solutions are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, even if the website only accepts SSL/TLS connections. Attackers could intercept the traffic to `http://example.com` (as requested by the user, even if `example.com` isn't even listening on that port) and replace it by making their own connection to `https://example.com`, proxy-ing it back to the user.

There was an [OWASP rule](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-_REMOVED_-_Do_Not_Perform_Redirects_from_Non-TLS_Page_to_TLS_Login_Page) against automatic redirections because of this. It was removed, probably be cause redirections are not a bad way to mitigate the risk (especially against passive eavesdroppers), but don't solve the fundamental problem.

There are various techniques you can use to guide the user to the HTTPS site, and it's not a bad idea to use them (although it won't protect them against active MITM attackers).

Firstly, if you don't have anything that should be served in plain HTTP at all on the webserver, turn off port 80 (e.g. remove `Listen 80` in Apache Httpd's configuration). The users will have to use `https://` at all times, which may be inconvenient.

Secondly, in your Apache Httpd configuration section for a particular path (either `Location` or `Directory`), use the [`SSLRequireSSL` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl): it will require usage of SSL/TLS (even if you've configured it on an alternative port in fact). Other web servers probably have similar directives.

Thirdly, you can use an redirection, either using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) or within your code (if it's an application). Something like this should do, for a specific location ([see the `HTTPS` special variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond); you can use 302 too, but 301 is better if this is to be more permanent):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(samples/.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**More importantly, make sure that all the links to that secure section use `https://`.** Never rely on the automatic redirection to do the job for you. For this reason, I'd recommend [not to use it at all during the development phase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105894/372643).

> However, I have noticed that I can still access the website
>   non-securely, ie. by using `http` instead of `https`.

This also sounds like you're using the same configuration for both `http` and `https`. If you're using Apache Httpd, I would suggest splitting the configuration into two distinct `VirtualHost`s: one for port 80 and one for port 443. They don't have to have exactly the same configuration: just don't put what's only for HTTPS in the HTTP virtual host at all.

---

A way to mitigate the problems mentioned above is to use [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), for browsers that support it (it applies to the entire host as far as I know). The very first connection may still be exposed if `https://` isn't used without the redirection, but it's possible to have a [pre-loaded list of sites expecting](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/sts) `https://` anyway (and enabled for HSTS).

Comment: Good information, how does gmail do this? - from the look of things they force https.

Comment: They use a redirection. This works fine, provided that you, as the user expects it to be `https://mail.google.com`. If, as a user, you see it work with `http://mail.google.com`, there probably is a MITM proxying the requests to the genuine `https://mail.google.com`. Unfortunately, Gmail can't do much about that if the users themselves don't check. Same principle as in real life: if Alice wants to talk to Bob, but talks to Chuck (who claims to be Bob) instead w/o verifying the ID, Bob won't know about this conversation and won't be able to do anything about it. It's Alice's responsibility.

Comment: I've seen some PHP scripts around that it will verify if connected with HTTPS and redirect if not using SSL to a HTTPS address. This is, of course, no easy task unless you are building your site now.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, that's exactly the same principle and that's what the rewrite rule from HTTP to HTTPS does. Whether you do it programmatically or by configuration doesn't matter, it's still a redirection with an initial request in plain HTTP, which presents the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to is redirect http traffic to https - [see this article 'Redirect http to https Apache secure connection – force HTTPS Connections'](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-apache-force-https-secure-connections.html).

For a [sub-directory](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/1897.htm) place this in a htaccess file in the directory itself.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCondition %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.maindomain.com/directory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you make this happen only for certain sub-directories?

Comment: @CraigJ sorry, missed the sub-directory part, answer updated.

Comment: While this is reduces the risks slightly, this doesn't work against active MITM attackers.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing access through HTTPS is in fact possible, besides being a required step in making your site MITM-, snooper- and PEBKAC-proof.  It shouldn't be the responsibility of the user, [that doesn't work](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/07/19/hope9talk.html).  Encourage your users to use secure browsers instead.

Forcing HTTPS is done through HSTS ([HTTP Strict-Transport-Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)).  Basic HSTS is secure after the first time the user has accessed your site over HTTPS (on all supporting browsers; [IE lacks the ability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzMFT.jpg)).  [Preloaded HSTS](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/) is always secure, and covers the modern fast-release browsers (Chromium and derivatives, Firefox).

For a more complete overview of HTTP security (addressing urls, redirects, cookies, and mixed content), see [this HTTPS migration howto](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oRXJUIttqQxuxmjj2tgYjj096IKw4Zcw6eAoIKWZ2oQ/preview).  HSTS is the last step in a progressive migration.  You don't really need to follow the order if your site is brand new.

Related standards: [secure cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) (important if your cookies live longer than the HSTS header), [HttpOnly cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) (while you're securing your cookies), [HPKP](https://raymii.org/s/articles/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning_Extension_HPKP.html) (for modern browsers and more resourceful attackers).