# DNS name/host-header specific url-pattern/security-constraint, to not require SSL with Tomcat6

Tags: dns, security, https, url-rewriting

I am needing to enable SSL on an application hosted through Tomcat6 and I have added the following to the tomcat web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

and setup the redirectPort as 443, in server.xml - this setup works fine.

I am needing to allow access to the application, without requiring SSL, when the app is accessed using a specific dns name.

For example:

the SSL certificate for the application is associated with the DNS name

**xyz.applicationdomain.com**

when the application is accessed with this name, a redirect occurs, and the URL changes to

**https://xyz.applicationdomain.com**

but when the application is accessed with

**abc.applicationdomain.com**, the application needs to be accessible without requiring SSL.

is it possible to implement this using another **security-constraint** definition?

Comment: NO, security constraints in web.xml only considers the context, not the domain.  You would need handle this I would think with a reverse proxy solution usiong apache or similar.   Two seperate virtual hosts would redirect to either the secure port 8443, or the insecure port 8080 of the tomcat container.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the `security-constraint` aspect. It's useful to a degree, but the redirection it entails [happens too late for actually securing the connection](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628). Never rely on automatic redirections to switch to HTTPS: it's should be done with links (and be expected by the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, security constraints in web.xml only considers the context, not the domain. You would need handle this I would think with a reverse proxy solution usiong apache or similar. Two seperate virtual hosts would redirect to either the secure port 8443, or the insecure port 8080 of the tomcat container.

Each context in server.xml would define the appropriate porxyhost and port to keep urls consistnet.

http://wiki.customware.net/repository/display/GREENHOUSE/2009/06/13/Reverse+Proxy+with+Apache+mod_proxy

Comment: essentially, this means that tomcat should (1) not be setup to do the redirect from http to https (2) be setup to listen on 8080 and 8443 - and use a reverse proxy solution to redirect traffic to 80 or 443 as needed for each incoming request URL - correct?