# https (SSL) instead of http for mobile users

Tags: https, mobile, bandwidth

I am building myself a new website, out of privacy and security concerns I am contemplating trying to make it https only.

It will be mobile-friendly using media queries but I am concerned--especially for mobile users--about the increased bandwidth.

How much will doing so increase my bandwidth or slow load times? For pages where I'm not transferring sensitive information, should I leave external links (to a jQuery library, or a web font for instance) in http?

Simply put, I have read articles saying the entire web would be more secure if everything was SSL but my actual knowledge of implementation is limited to payment gateways and log-in pages and such. I apologize for the open-ended nature of the question but anything, even just simple answers to the specific questions is welcomed.

Comment: Original search of this site didn't turn up a suitable answer but I followed a few related links threads and found info indicating this probably isn't a good idea. For instance, apparently YouTube videos (which I sometimes make and embed) is not served over https, and while the post was 2 years ago, apparently there can be caching and/or indexing problems. If this incorrect or out of date please detail. Thanks

Comment: If external links (to a jQuery library) are HTTP on an HTTPS page then the user will get notified that "this page contains insecure content".

Comment: While the answers in this thread have all been quite good, I do want to note that in the last couple days I started to learn about the [SPDY](https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/) Apache settings (handlers? protocols?). That speed up, and from my understanding compress, SSL connections. So if you come across this down the road, you should look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You may be interested in [this related question on SO: *Make full site HTTPS / SSL? What performance issues & best practices still apply in 2012?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11645099/372643))

How much will doing so increase my bandwidth or slow load times?

Once the handshake has completed, the encryption is done using symmetric keys. There is a bit of overhead for the SSL/TLS records, but it's actually quite small (according to [Google engineers](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html), there's about 2% of network overhead).

What's costly is the handshake (both in terms of CPU and network). Without session resumption, you'll have to get the server certificate (about 1KB for a cert with a 2048-bit RSA key, this depends on the attributes). The round trips can also increase latency (and might be a bigger problem on mobile devices). I presume some mobile devices at least support session resumption.

The biggest handshake traffic I've seen were due to a long certification authorities list in the Certificate Request TLS message, when using client-certificate authentication. This was configured with a default trust store (on a Java server). A good server setting can avoid this problem (when you use client-cert authentication, you can usually limit yourself to a few CAs you're willing to accept, from a server point of view, you don't need the default list, which in this case had 100+ names).
If you're not even using client-certificate authentication at all, make sure you don't enable it (even optionally), so that you won't have this problem.

> For pages where I'm not transferring sensitive information, should I
>   leave external links (to a jQuery library, or a web font for instance)
>   in http?

Yes, never mix content. It defeats the purpose of HTTPS. The issue with mixed content is that you no longer know which part of the page you can trust. It's a UI issue (and mobile browsers are already quite poor in terms of making it clear what security conditions you're under).

You can use CDNs that support HTTPS if you need ([Google Libraries API](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) provide `https://` links, for example, including for jQuery).
Modern browsers should cache HTTPS content by default, although some might not, in which case you can use the `Cache-Control: public` header. You should also prevent caching of the sensitive pages.

Comment: In the newest (a few months old) Google styleguide for HTML & CSS [link](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml) they advocate omitting the protocol so that resources can be accessed by whatever means are appropriate. That ability is news to me.

Comment: @user1332729, indeed, that makes sense if their CDN have the same URL mapping between `http://` and `https://` (I was just pointing out that they were offering `https://` here).

Comment: apparently I took too long editing that last comment...I hit return for a new paragraph and it posted. Oh well, thanks for the link I'll read more carefully and process.

Comment: @user1332729, after re-reading your comment at the top, [this](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/02/https-support-for-youtube-embeds.html) should be of interest (if you haven't seen it already from the other question I've linked to).

Answer (score 4):

The bandwidth shouldn't increase by that much. There's a bit of extra negotiation when an https connection is set up, and because encryption pads things out to a certain block size pages might get slightly bigger.

The load times might increase because of the overhead in encrypting the page at your end and decrypting the page at the user's end. I can't say by how much because I don't know your hardware and neither of us know how powerful the user's mobile devices are.

If you have a secure page with non-secure content then the user's browser may give a worrying error message.

I would only encrypt the pages with sensitive information on them.

Comment: I always thought that HTTPS content is not cached by the browser, hence the increase in bandwidth (and slower response) since the browser will _always_ request a new page? Is this not the case (anymore)?

Comment: According to this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174348/will-web-browsers-cache-content-over-https they probably will cache content.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everybody. When I did a little more digging (as noted above) what I found was basically the issues you all raised: the mixed content warning; added bandwidth for encryption/decryption; sites that don't serve linked or embedded content over SSL; questions about indexing, SEO, and cache. In short, while I will keep it in mind, right now there are too many unknowns for me to risk the problems when I have enough on my plate with a re-design. Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

HTTPS does not offer any strong security - since it is vulnerable to a MiTM attack. It just makes it a bit harder (just a bit). I don't see the advantage gain over the cost for having a full https site.

Comment: HTTPS is not vulnerable to MITM attacks, if the user has normal certificate verification in place. That's the whole point.

Comment: @Bruno: Google "sslstrip" and use your brain. Considering this "bam,wham,thank you ma'm" tool exists since 2009, you may want to rethink your voting policy, if you get my drift.

Comment: You don't seem to know how sslstrip works. It MITM-attacks the HTTP connection *before* getting to HTTPS, for those who rely on an upgrade, or spoofs the cert with its own (which you won't trust). If you *expect* HTTPS to start with, and if you get a certificate you trust, you're OK.

Comment: From the [sslstrip page](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/): "*It will transparently hijack HTTP traffic on a network, watch for HTTPS links and redirects, then map those links into either look-alike HTTP links or homograph-similar HTTPS links.*". That's an attack against upgrades and initial HTTP content, not against HTTPS. That's why [HSTS is useful](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628).

Comment: @Bruno: When you decide on security issues, you don't care about the theoretical dangers, but the practical. Can an attacker use ssltool ar any other similar while on a MitM scenario to get your unencrypted traffic today? Sure. End of story. Maybe you can mitigate it or not, make a random survey about it and see how many actually know how to stop it. I don't care if SSL is theoretically secure or not - I do care that it is used as an excuse for security, when in practice it offers none. Finally "an attack against upgrades and initial HTTP content" is too generic to actually make sense.

Comment: No, they can't. I connect to my bank website using `https://mybank/` directly, and I don't ignore certificate warnings: sslstrip doesn't work here. Again, sslstrip attacks the content obtained via plain HTTP, to prevent you from getting the `https://` links (or rediction). If you *expect* HTTPS for a site, you're OK. Again, that's why HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) is being deployed, to make sure browser expect HTTPS when it's available.

Comment: @john - Do you recommend not to care about security, because nothing is 100% safe? HTTPS allows the user to prevent a MITM attack if he really cares, that's much better than offering nothing. The 50 dollars are well spent, especially if you consider, that SSL-Strip needs control over the user's access point, before you can start the attack. BTW do you know a better way to prevent MITM attacks?

Comment: @martinstoeckli - I recommend awareness for the devs. Use the tech if you like, but know its practical shortcomings. The fact that no-one else raising the issue on this topic says something about how the majority of us opt in taking a "it should be fine" approach on security.

Comment: There is a related Q&A on the IT Security site... http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19616/why-is-it-possible-to-sniff-an-https-ssl-request